# Using icloud as a Database storage

Tags: icloud

I have copy my sqlite DB in icloud and I want to use that icloud sqlite DB as insert/update and delete. I did code for it but it is not working in other device(I have 2 devices). Means when I perform any DB operation it is working for one this other device does not show any change in device. If I Insert one record in iPhone it does not show in iPad. I am useing copyItemAtPath,removeItemAtPath and removeItemAtURL methods from FileMenager class.

It's really urgent.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend to use Core Data.

Comment: I think Core Data can insert/delete more than one data, too. If you use raw SQLite, you must do all the synchronization by yourself. But I heard that Core Data does the synchronization automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CoreData + iCloud. Check out https://devforums.apple.com/thread/126670?tstart=0 you should have Developer acc to access the forum.